# Prove the existence of a continouosly differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$$ E\textrm{ is a closed subset of }\mathbb{R}.\: \: \: \: k \in\mathbb{Z}^{+}.\: \:   \\
\textrm{Prove that }\exists f\in C^{k}(\mathbb{R})\: \textrm{ such that  }E=f^{-1}\left \{ 0 \right \}$$
I know this is true when E is a closed and bounded interval. How to show it is true in other cases?

Comment: Any open subset of $\mathbb R$ is the disjoint union of countably or finitely many intervals.

Comment: using your suggestion i can prove there exists continuous function on R which is zero exactly at the points of E. but what after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For any $a,b$ with $a <b$ let $f(x)=e^{-\frac 1  { (x-a)(b-x)}}$ for $a<x<b$ and $0$ for all other $x$. Then $f$ is infinitely differentiable and all its derivatives are $0$ at $a$ and $b$. Do this for each interval in the complement of your closed set.

Comment: thanks this is very helpful